# Web Api Action Attribute not executing when request sent from a new tab

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an Action Attribute

```
ReportAccessAttribute
```

Added this attribute to a controller action

```
ReportingController
```

My application is in angularjs
When tested with other controller and action this attribute works fine.

Now I am requesting that Action method of controller from my application by setting the url in an anchor tag.
This anchor tag opens a new tab and sends the request to server.
In this case Action attribute do not execute.

Please suggest.

Code Sample
Action Attribute

```
public class ReportAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //Some work...!!
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class ReportingController : Controller
{
    public ReportingController()
    {
        //Some initializations..!!
    }

    [Filters.ReportAccess]
    public ActionResult Report(string reportName)
    {
        //Report generation logic.
    }
}
```

When accessed from my angularjs app it gets executed eg: using a service to call that method.

But when I create a url and set anchor tag value to that url and click on that anchor tag. It opens that url in new tab and then it don't executes.

Comment: show some example of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Actually the code is pretty standard. Nothing specific. Its actually a scenario based. When that link which points to that action method is clicked I expect that attribute to be executed. but its not..:( If that req is sent simply from inside the application then it executes.

Comment: Is this really asp.net-web-api or is this strictly Angular?  I'll echo @AmitKumarGhosh and say that providing some example code would really help.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh added code sample. Its pretty standard.

Comment: you are using ASP.Net MVC with angular?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.

The problem was I create the attribute using namespaces from WebApi dll and the controller from MVC dll.

That's why it wasn't intercepted in the execution pipeline.